# best way to make nested lists?

Tags: python, list

which among the following is the best approach for a very large list ?

```
    >>> nested_list=[ [0 for x in xrange(10)] for y in xrange(10)]
    >>>  nested_list=[ [0]*10]*20
    >>>  nested_list=[]
    >>>  for x in xrange(20):
    ....     for y in xrange(10):
     ....        nested_list.append([0])
```

Comment: Depends if it is a nested list of mutable or immutable objects...

Comment: This is a very vague question... What kind of a list do you want? random numbers?

Comment: `numpy.zeros((20,10,1))`

Comment: @dawg assuming objects are mutable ?

Comment: `[ [0 for x in xrange(10)] for y in xrange(10)]` is most likely what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should, in general, be careful with the construct of:

```
>>> li=[[None]*3]*3
>>> li
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Because you have replicated multiple references to the same object. Modify one:

```
>>> li[0][1]=True
```

You modify all in (sometimes) a surprising way for Python Newbies:

```
>>> li
[[None, True, None], [None, True, None], [None, True, None]]
```

Note that the middle element of all nested lists are changed with the assignment `li[0][1]=True`

Where the other methods you have there are creating a *different* type of nesting:

```
>>> nli=[ [None for x in xrange(3)] for y in xrange(4)]
>>> nli
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> nli[0][1]=True
>>> nli
[[None, True, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Note, as expected, only one element is changed by the assignment of `nli[0][1]=True`